# Stop the "upload file size" error from printing

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, errors

I am running a woocommerce site on wordpress.  I have updated to the latest versions.

I am seeing that on some pages in the shop that there is an error printing on the page:

```
Trying to upload files larger than 256M is not allowed!
```

My question is not how to fix it, but what file is generating that error message, and how to stop it printing. The page is loading as a shop page, and nothing is being uploaded, so I do not need to see the error!

Comment: Hi Jon - unfortunately I don't think anyone is going to be able to help you with such limited info. Can you try and rule out the issue by a) using a default theme like Twenty Fifteen b) disabling all plugins c) reactivating them one by one until you find the cause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a plugin the was trying to upload on Woocommerce pages, that was failing.  The updated plugin worked.

I am leaving this question as I saw on others had the issue on the wordpress site